# Transposing mysql column to row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
NAME1       NAME2       NAME2    RECNO
Nailtech    Deekay      Pooja    564
```

I need help in transposing the above mySQl query result to as follows

[image]

Comment: Please add more details, expected output, Since you have two columns as "NAEM2"

Comment: Does your table have a single row?